# find sublist by using recursive generator in python

Tags: python, list, recursion, generator, nested-lists

The nested list is like:

```
nested_list=['a', ['b', ['c', 'd', 'e'], 'f', ['g', 'h']], 'i', ['j', 'k']]
```

and we can clearly see its structure:

- a

  - b

    - c
    - d
    - e
  - f

    - g
    - h
- i

  - j
  - k

Here is the thing I want to do: define find_sublist(keywords, nested_list) function to show if:
`find_sublist('a', nested_list)` 
returns
`['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']` all the sublist in flattend list
or
`find_sublist('b', nested_list)` returns
`['b','c','d','e']`

I oringinally tried:

The idea is to make a *boolen* flag found in the parameter list. The flag stays as *False* at the beginning and is set to True when the function recurs to the sublist of list. In the base case, the category can also be yield when the flag is True.

```
def find_sublist(keywords, nested_list, found=False):
            if type(nested_list) == list:
                for index, child in enumerate(nested_list):
                    yield from find_sublist(keywords, child, found=False)
                    if child == keywords and index+1 < len(nested_list) and type(nested_list[index+1]) == list:
                        yield from find_sublist(keywords, nested_list[index+1], found=True)
            else:
                if nested_list == keywords or found==True:
                    yield nested_list
```

And I the result by using this example:
`[i for i in find_sublist('a', nested_list)]`
is `['a']`

And I tried another code and changed `yield from find_sublist(keywords, nested_list[index+1], found=True)` to `yield from nested_list[index+1]`

the result with the example `[i for i in find_sublist('a', nested_list)]`
is `['a','b',['c','d','e'],'f',['g','h']]`

Originally, the purpose of using `yield from find_sublist(keywords, nested_list[index+1], found=True)` is to recursively call the generator on the sublists with flag set to true when the target is found.
I was wondering is the probelm occurred in this part. But I can't figure it out. :(

Comment: Will the values in the lists always be unique? If not, what should happen when you call `find_sublist('a', nested_list)` and there is more than one `'a'` somewhere in the lists?

Comment: Just so that we are clear: `nested_list` has 4 members. And when I pass the first member (`'a'`) to `find_sublist` you want it to return the first two members (flattened)?

Comment: Yes. Every element in list is unique and when I pass the first member (```'a'```), I'd like to print out all the sublist under ```'a'```(included itself with flatten list). I use ```yield from``` instead of constructing another flatten function to pass this idea.

Comment: @VivianChen Suppose the input is `['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e']]`. What should searching for `'b'` return?

Comment: hi, the input is always the nested list ```nested_list```. When I pass the code ```find_sublist('b', nested_list)``` is to find all the sublist included itselt in flatten list in nested_list.

Comment: Why `find_sublist('b', nested_list)` returns `['b','c','d','e']` instead of `['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']`?

Comment: hi, you can see the structure ```[ 'c',' d', 'e ']```  is under ```['b']```

Comment: @VivianChen You haven't really explained what the structure is. In some places, a letter is followed by a list, but in others places it isn't. Why? What is the purpose of the structure?

Comment: @VivianChen In your example in the question, what do you expect `find_sublist('d', nested_list)` to return?

Comment: This nested list is like a category, the purpose is I'd like to find the subcategory including itself. So, if I search to the right category and next element in ```nested_list``` is not a list then stop. If it is list print all the list and keep search the next index recursively.

Comment: If passing ```find_sublist('d', nested_list)``` , it will return just ```['d']``` . There is no list next to it.

Comment: @VivianChen What you want is to list all elements from the starting point up until the recursion returns to the same depth. So you must increment a depth variable with each level of recursion and also record the current depth when the key element is first found. When the current depth equals the starting depth, you can raise an exception to break out of the recursion. This will require an embedded function so that the state variables can be maintained in the outer function scope. Although it might sound somewhat complicated, the resulting function could actually be fairly simple.

Comment: But it's not under. It's next to. Your requirements don't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
Use only the generator:

```
>>> def flat(it):
...     for val in it:
...         if isinstance(val, list):
...             yield from flat(val)
...         else:
...             yield val
...
>>> def find_sublist(val, nested_list):
...     for front, back in pairwise(nested_list):
...         if val == front:
...             yield front
...             if isinstance(back, list):
...                 yield from flat(back)
...             break
...         if isinstance(back, list):
...             yield from find_sublist(val, back)
...
>>> list(find_sublist('a', nested_list))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
>>> list(find_sublist('b', nested_list))
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

If you really want to combine them into one generator function:

```
def find_sublist(val, nested_list, found=False):
    if found:
        for elem in nested_list:
            if isinstance(elem, list):
                yield from find_sublist(val, elem, True)
            else:
                yield elem
        return

    for front, back in pairwise(nested_list):
        if val == front:
            yield front
            if isinstance(back, list):
                yield from find_sublist(val, back, True)
            break
        if isinstance(back, list):
            yield from find_sublist(val, back)
```

To be honest, I think it's not elegant. It not only increases the difficulty of coding, but also causes the loss of performance.

---

**Old Answer**
First define an auxiliary function for flattening:

```
>>> def flatten(lst):
...     def flat(it):
...         for val in it:
...             if isinstance(val, list):
...                 yield from flat(val)
...             else:
...                 yield val
...     return list(flat(lst))
...
```

Then use `pairwise` if the version of your python is 3.10+:

```
>>> from itertools import pairwise
>>> def find_sublist(val, nested_list):
...     for front, back in pairwise(nested_list):
...         if val == front:
...             if isinstance(back, list):
...                 return flatten((front, back))
...             else:
...                 return [front]
...         if isinstance(back, list) and (result := find_sublist(val, back)):
...             return result
...
>>> nested_list=['a', ['b', ['c', 'd', 'e'], 'f', ['g', 'h']], 'i', ['j', 'k']]
>>> find_sublist('a', nested_list)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
>>> find_sublist('b', nested_list)
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

If not, you can also define it yourself:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    try:
        front = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    for back in iterator:
        yield front, back
        front = back
```

Comment: Yes. thank you. I know how to use flatten function. I just confused and want to fix my  code with recursive generator.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the two tasks into separate functions. One to find the sublist and one to flatten it.

I also had a few runs through the debugger with the recursive generator. I found it was continuing the `for` loop in earlier nested calls once it had found an answer in later nested calls. Adding the `if not found:`
before the `raise` at the end resolved this

```
def find_sublist(keywords, nested_list: list):
    found = False
    for i, sub_element in enumerate(nested_list):
        if sub_element == keywords:
            next_element = nested_list[i+1]
            if isinstance(next_element, list): #could be more generic by checking for Sequence
                yield from [keywords] + [item for item in flatten_list(next_element)]
                found = True
            else:
                yield keywords
                found = True
        elif isinstance(sub_element, list):
            try:
                yield from find_sublist(keywords, sub_element)
                found = True
            except ValueError:
                pass
    if not found:
        raise ValueError("{kw} not found in nested_list".format(kw=keywords))


def flatten_list(list_to_flatten: list):
    for item in list_to_flatten:
        if not isinstance(item, list):
            yield item
        else:
            yield from flatten_list(item)
```

The above will search through the list from top to bottom and return the results from the each instance of `keywords`. As you said they will be unique then I assume this should be fine otherwise you can add a check for `found` and then `break` the `for` loop if `True`.

If the `keyword` is not followed by a sublist but rather by another element at the same level then it returns a list with one entry `keywords` (eg: `find_sublist("d", nested_list)` in your example returns `["d"]`

Finally if `keywords` is not found you will get a `ValueError`

Happy to explain any of the workings in more detail, or help to adjust any specific detail if needed

Put another way. This will pass the following pytest testcases:

```
from pytest import raises
from .NestedSublists import find_sublist

nested_list=['a', ['b', ['c', 'd', 'e'], 'f', ['g', 'h']], 'i', ['j', 'k']]

def test_a():
    assert [x for x in find_sublist('a', nested_list)] == ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']

def test_b():
    assert [x for x in find_sublist('b', nested_list)] == ['b','c','d','e']

def test_b2():
    nested_list2=['a', ['b', ['c', 'd', 'e'], 'f', ['g', 'h']], 'b', ['j', 'k']]
    assert [x for x in find_sublist('b', nested_list2)] == ['b','c','d','e', 'b', 'j', 'k']

def test_notfound():
    with raises(ValueError) as e:
        [x for x in find_sublist("z",nested_list)]
    assert str(e.value) == "z not found in nested_list"

def test_noSublist():
    nested_list2=['a', ['b', ['c', 'd', 'e'], 'f', ['g', 'h']], "p", 'b', ['j', 'k']]
    assert [x for x in find_sublist("p", nested_list2)] == ["p"]

def test_f():
    assert [x for x in find_sublist("f", nested_list)] == ["f", "g", "h"]
```

Comment: Thank you. But my purpose is to combine this two function by using recursive generator like my code above.

Comment: @VivianChen It's better to break down a task properly than to complete it rudely. Only passing through one recursive function will not only increase the difficulty of coding, but also cause the loss of performance.

Comment: Yes, I know :(. But I feel like I almost complete the code I write.

Comment: Hi @VivianChen - does the tip with using if found: at the end after the for loop help? I think you could combine them in that way if you really want to